# The list fragment that i have included in my android project doesn't seem to have invoked at runtime

Tags: java, android

I have extended list fragment(list fragment consists of a listview by default) in my android project and i have set an address list adapter(custom adapter) extending array adapter to pass information to list view.But I'm unable to view any output on the emulator.How can I overcome this problem?

I tried including a toast message to see if my onCreate overridden method was called, but the toast message didnt appear on the emulator. I dont think know if the list fragment was called at run time. AddressBook is my singleton class.My xml file consists only a textview.

```
public class AddressListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<NameAndAddress> mNameAndAddress;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mNameAndAddress=AddressBook.getInstance().getBook();
        AddressListAdapter adapter=new AddressListAdapter(mNameAndAddress);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"onCreate from list fragment",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//it didn't appear on the screen.
    }
    private class AddressListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NameAndAddress>{
        public AddressListAdapter(ArrayList<NameAndAddress> nameAndAddresses){
            super(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item,nameAndAddresses);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView,@NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
            }

            NameAndAddress temp=getItem(position);

            TextView textView=convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            textView.setText(temp.getmName());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect my output to have a listview through extending the list fragment method.

```
public class NameAndAddress implements Serializable {
    private String mName;

    public String getmName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public String getmAddress() {
        return mAddress;
    }

    public String getmAddress2() {
        return mAddress2;
    }

    public String getmZipcode() {
        return mZipcode;
    }

    private String mAddress;
    private String mAddress2;
    private String mZipcode;


    public NameAndAddress(String mName, String mAddress, String mAddress2, String mZipcode) {
        this.mName = mName;
        this.mAddress = mAddress;
        this.mAddress2 = mAddress2;
        this.mZipcode = mZipcode;
    }

}
```

Comment: post your listfragment code and xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: What I have posted is my list fragment code.I have not used list fragment elsewhere.

Comment: you have written extends listFragment. so what is list fragment??? and i think  posted code is about AddressListFragment

Comment: Addresslistfragment is my class.List fragment is inbuilt class in android.List fragment is a fragment that displays a list of items by binding to a data source such as an array or Cursor, and exposes event handlers when the user selects an item.

ListFragment hosts a ListView object that can be bound to different data sources, typically either an array or a Cursor holding query results.It can  bind screen layout and row layout.

Comment: List fragment has a default layout with a single list view.

Comment: Hey..I tried your code...its working fine on my machine...its showing list...just instead of nameaddress object i created my own list...can you tell me what is addressbook....can you post nameAndAddress class..because everything other is same and its working..please check whether you are getting nameAndAddress values using debugger...or try it on real device

Comment: AddressBook is my singleton class where i stored the data.

Comment: Did u create an instance for the AddresslistFragment class?if so, i want to know where?

Comment: Im having trouble creating instance for this AddressListFragment class.

Comment: post the code how you are calling AddressListFragment...I used fragment transaction to call addressList Fragment

Comment: Can you please show me that because when I tried fragment manger i got error.

Comment: FragmentManager myfragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction myfragmentTransaction = myfragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        AddressListFragment myfragment = new AddressListFragment();

        myfragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_item, myfragment);
        myfragmentTransaction.commit()

Comment: what is your list_item..is it frame layout

Comment: just a text view, my main activity has frame layout

Comment: check my answer..and let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. you are using below code for transaction

```
FragmentManager myfragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); 
FragmentTransaction myfragmentTransaction = 
myfragmentManager.beginTransaction();  

AddressListFragment myfragment = new AddressListFragment(); 
myfragmentTransaction.add(R.id.list_item, myfragment); 
myfragmentTransaction.commit();
```

but from your code list_item is layout file. You will need frame layout to replace.add frame layout ID from main activity in place of list_item.

also when i tried your code Its showing FragmentManager is depricated so you can use below code

```
 AddressListFragment myfragment = new AddressListFragment() ;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = 
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() ;
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout_id, myfragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Hope this will help you